# How add icon in QListView using QStringListModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qstringlistmodel

Is somehow possible to add icons to a ListView using a QStringListModel ?

This is what I'm doing.

```
QStringListModel* model;
QStringList List;
model->setStringList(List);
ui->listView->setModel(model);
...

model->setData(index, "Test");
model->setData(index,QIcon(":/icon.png"),Qt::DecorationRole);
```

unfortunately the icon does not appears on the list.

How can I add icons to the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`QStringListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html) does not support roles other than `DisplayRole` and `EditRole`.

Use [`QStandardItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) instead in order to display icons via `DecorationRole`:

```
auto model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
ui->listView->setModel(model);
model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(QIcon(":/icon.png"), "Test"));
```